# How to make sure that $S$ & $S^{-1}$($S$ inverse) is a permutation of bytes?

Tags: aes, s-boxes

Assume you have implemented the S-box and Inverse S-box of AES as code (or hardware) instead of a lookup table copy-pasted from the AES standard. An obvious test you want do is to check that S−1(S(B)) = B for each byte B. However, this only proves that S−1 is an inverse of S. What do you need to check to make sure that S (and hence S−1) is a permutation of bytes? To complete your test, you must check that S(B) is correct for every B by matching it to the standard. If you have done the two first checks, how many bytes B can you skip checking against the standard?

Comment: Firstly, [NIST provides examples](https://csrc.nist.gov/CSRC/media/Projects/Cryptographic-Standards-and-Guidelines/documents/examples/AES_Core128.pdf). Secondly, the AES SBox is 8-bit input to 8-bit output, so you need a table of size 256x2 to test an Sbox. [Wikipedia has C code that can be used](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rijndael_S-box) as test base.

Comment: If it wasn't a permutation, the inverse test would have failed.